# Ошибка сборки при Platform Toolset v141_xp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Пустой консольный проект студии 2017, с настройками по умолчанию, кроме `Platform Toolset: v141_xp`, с таким кодом:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Дает ошибку при компиляции:

> Error C2760 syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected
>   'type specifier'  myproject c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\objbase.h  239

Строка 239 в файле objbase.h (с комментарием "make sure everyone..."):

```
extern "C++"
{
    template<typename T> void** IID_PPV_ARGS_Helper(T** pp) 
    {
        static_cast<IUnknown*>(*pp);    // make sure everyone derives from IUnknown
        return reinterpret_cast<void**>(pp);
    }
}
```

Если переключить Platform Toolset на v141 (без поддержки WindowsXP) то собирается нормально.

Что означает эта ошибка и как заставить компилироваться такой код?

Comment: А какие у вас дефайны для контроля SDK объявлены?

Comment: @VTT `WINVER=0x0501`, `WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` (они имеются в виду?)

Comment: А если добавить `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` и `STRICT`?

Comment: @VTT с WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN собирается без ошибок

Comment: Видимо это сввязано с опцией /permissive, которая в VS2017 сделана включенной по умолчанию. Вот тут про это пишут: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/174539/objbaseh-error-when-compiling-with-permissive-and.html А WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN исключает заголовки OLE и просто прячет ошибку (если они вам не нужны, то и так сойдет)